# Should electron-packager distribution files be included in version control?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have set electron-builder to build into my dist folder which is currently not being tracked by version control. I use git as my VCS and Github as my remote repository.

I recently included electron-packager and I now want to publish to GitHub but I'm not so sure if I should include the dist folder in version control or whether electron-builder will handle publishing and I won't have to push the build files to git.

Comment: It's up to you. Normally you wouldn't include dist files in version control because that would increase merge conflicts and repository size. For publishing, you should look into [github releases](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/releasing-projects-on-github).

Comment: I don't include it. I do include the "build" folder.